# Problema al obtener datos de distintos combobox's

Tags: java

Realize un programa que me permite crear una hora, con horas, minutos, y segundos. Para ello utilice un combobox para poder elejir entre A.M o P.M, de modo que cual fuese el la elecion del usuario, deberia mostrar otro combobox y escojer de alli Horas de A.M o P.M. La problematica que tengo es que cuando escojo la opcion A.M, ya que esta no establece dicha hora en mi label, mientras que si escojo P.M, la hora si se establece normalmente, asi que ¿alguien podria decirme que estoy haciendo mal?
La cuestion es que debo poder obtener las horas de ambos combobox segun el modo que elija, pero esto solo me funciona con el modo P.M

vista previa del programa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el codigo:

```
  private void btnConstruirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    //Aqui intento intento guardar la hora del combobox en modo A.M, y no funciona
     if(cbxAM.getSelectedItem()== null)
    {
        aux1= "00";
    }
    else
    {

       aux1= cbxAM.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }
     hora = aux1;
    //Aqui intento guardar las horas del combobox del modo P.M, y funciona
    if(cbxPM.getSelectedItem()== null)
    {
        aux2= "00";
    }
    else
    {

       aux2= cbxPM.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }
    hora= aux2;


    if(cbxMinutos.getSelectedItem()== null)
    {
        minuto= "00";
    }
    else
    {
        minuto= cbxMinutos.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

     if(cbxSegundos.getSelectedItem()== null)
    {
        segundo= "00";
    }
    else
    {
        segundo=cbxSegundos.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

    //Creo un objeto t con abributos que obtengo de los combobox
    //Los atributos minuto y segundo tambien los obtengo de comboboxes
    //El atributo hora, es el unico que recibe datos de 2 comobox, A.M y P.M
    //Pero solo me establece en pantalla el valor escojido en el combobox P.M
    PruebaTiempo t = new PruebaTiempo(hora, minuto, segundo);

    if(t.insertarTiempo().getHora().equalsIgnoreCase("00"))
    {
    lblhora.setText("00");
    }
    else 
    {
      //Despliego por pantalla la hora de los modos A.M Y P.M, pero solo establece el dato de P.M
      lblhora.setText(t.insertarTiempo().getHora()); 
    }

    if(t.insertarTiempo().getMinuto().equalsIgnoreCase("00"))
    {
    lblminuto.setText("00");
    }
    else 
    {
      //Funciona correcto
      lblminuto.setText(t.insertarTiempo().getMinuto());
    }

    if(t.insertarTiempo().getSegundo().equalsIgnoreCase("00"))
    {
    lblsegundo.setText("00");
    }
    else 
    {
     ////Funciona correcto
      lblsegundo.setText(t.insertarTiempo().getSegundo());  
    }

    if(lblhora.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")&&lblminuto.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")&&lblsegundo.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        btnConstruir.setText("Construir");
    }
    else
    {
        btnConstruir.setText("Editar");  
    }



}                                            

private void btnConstruir1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    btnConstruir.setText("Construir");
    lblhora.setText("00");
    lblminuto.setText("00");
    lblsegundo.setText("00");
    cbxPM.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    cbxAM.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    cbxMinutos.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    cbxSegundos.setSelectedIndex(-1);

}                                             

private void cbxZONEActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    zone=cbxZONE.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(zone.equalsIgnoreCase("A.M"))
    {
        cbxAM.setEnabled(true);
        cbxPM.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else if(zone.equalsIgnoreCase("P.M"))
    {

        cbxAM.setEnabled(false);
        cbxPM.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido poner las 15 para AM o PM ya que solo se establece desde 1 a 12 no?

Answer (score 0):

Veo un par de problemas en tu código.`

1º

Según tu imagen, la selección de AM o PM es un combobox, pero luego veo que recoges valor de dos combobox distintos.

`if(cbxAM.getSelectedItem()== null)`

`if(cbxPM.getSelectedItem()== null)`

Esta claro que es para coger el valor de la hora, pero no tiene sentido doblar el combobox de hora, dando uno para el AM y otro para PM, cuando en ambos casos, va a tener las mismas opciones.

Debido a este desdoblamiento, estas cometiendo el siguiente error.

2º

En este fragmento de codigo, desblues del bloque `cbxAM`, seteas `hora = aux1;`.

Depues en el bloque `cbxPM`, vuelves a setear `hora = aux2;`

**Estas sobrescribiendo el valor de hora con el de tu comboPM siempre.**

```
 if(cbxAM.getSelectedItem()== null)
{
    aux1= "00";
}
else
{

   aux1= cbxAM.getSelectedItem().toString();
}
 hora = aux1;
//Aqui intento guardar las horas del combobox del modo P.M, y funciona
if(cbxPM.getSelectedItem()== null)
{
    aux2= "00";
}
else
{

   aux2= cbxPM.getSelectedItem().toString();
}
hora= aux2;
```

---

**Solución**: Quita uno de los combobox de horas. Tampoco necesitaras los valores auxiliares y haz una ultima ocndicion para si se selecciona las 12 PM para que se ponga en 00.

```
if(cbxHora.getSelectedItem()== null)
{
    hora= "00";
}
else
{

   hora= cbxPM.getSelectedItem().toString();
}

if(zone.equalsIgnoreCase("P.M") && hora.equals("12"))
{
   hora="00";
}
```

Y como te ha dicho en los comentarios Valentín Sánchez Boto, no tiene sentido que en el campo horas puedas elegir mas de las 12.

Comment: La razón por la estableci 2 combobox, fue por que queria que las horas se establecan en formato de 24 horas, es decir, de 00 a 12 del dia para A.M, y de 13 a 23 P.M, en realidad, no es lo mismo. En cambio, si lo vez de la manera para selecionar entre A.M y P.M solo con un formato de 12 horas, la cosa cambia. es percepcion supongo.

Comment: Aunque si estoy consiente de que aquello se lo podria manejar facilmente por interno con codigo. Es verdad, no tenia bien ordenadas mis ideas, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si procedes a un formato 24 horas, el AM y PM es totalmente innecesario. Igualmente si quieres mantenerlo entonces sabes que `hora>='12:00'?PM:AM`